# BigQuery Data Transfer API, requestedRunTime only in the past?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm setting up an automated job to trigger a GCP BigQuery Data Transfer task. The Data Transfer Config is all set up correctly and everything works like a charm when I'm running it on-demand via the GCP console. To trigger the job via the API, I'm using the [`https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/startManualRuns`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/startManualRuns) endpoint, and that's all working okay, too.

But I'm very confused about one piece of the documentation. The docs describe the payload parameter `requestedRunTime` as the "specific runTime for a transfer run to be started. **The requestedRunTime must not be in the future.**" (emphasis mine). When requesting a job to execute, I do not understand how the `requestedRunTime` could (or should) ever be in the past. Does this make sense to anyone? Perhaps this is actually a typo, and it should say, "requestedRunTime must be in the future"?

Comment: Based on my understanding the [requestedRunTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/startManualRuns#request-body) specifies the date and time of the data should be ingested and it must be in the past.